# How to enable mysql support in Komodo 7.1?

Tags: windows, linux, komodo

In Komodo 6 I can connect to my mysql database but not in Komodo 7.1? When I want to add my mysql connection to Komodo it gives me sqlite 3 support only?! How can I add my mysql connection to Komodo 7.1? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the mysql.xpi extension in Komodo: http://community.activestate.com/xpi/mysql-database-explorer[image]